# Floating point arithmetics using to nearest

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Concerning the library fenv.h in C, I have some difficulties to understand what the rounding direction mode does when using fesetround() and the direction FE_TONEAREST (default) in particular.

There are 4 types of rounding directions in the library :

- FE_TONEAREST
- FE_UPWARD
- FE_DOWNWARD
- FE_TOWARDZERO

On doubles :

```
double res = 0.14*50;
printf ("res = %.50lf \n",res);
```

This returns : `res = 7.00000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625`
(the compiler says that res > 7)

However, on floats :

```
float res = 0.14*50;
printf ("res = %.50f \n",res);
```

returns `7.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (res = 7)

On long doubles :

```
long double a;
long double b;
scanf("%Lf",&a);
scanf("%Lf",&b);
long double res = a*b;
printf("%.50Lf \n",res);
```

returns `7.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (res = 7)

Is the double type more risky for floating point arithmetics on the FE_TONEAREST mode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with the round-to-nearest rounding mode, which is the default mode anyway. The answer to your question is that `0.14f` is different from `0.14` is different from `0.14L` **and none of them is equal to the mathematical ratio of 14 / 100**. These (different) numbers `0.14f`, `0.14` and `0.14L` behave differently when multiplied by 50.

The rounding mode affects the behavior of the multiplication, not the value of `0.14f`, `0.14` and `0.14L`(*). The reason why `0.14 * 50 > 7` relates as much to the value of `0.14` than it does to the behavior of `*`. Therefore, do not assume that the rounding mode in which `*` is executed alone explains what you see.

> Is the double type more risky for floating point arithmetics on the FE_TONEAREST mode ?

No, absolutely not.

---

Note that your `float` experiment should be `float res = 0.14f*50;` in order to be meaningful. Otherwise, you are multiplying a double-precision constant `0.14` and then rounding the result to float. It is normal for this operation to produce the mathematical result more often than multiplying a single-precision decimal constant does, but again this has nothing to do with the rounding mode and everything to do with the actual operand of the multiplication.

---

(*) C99 6.4.4.2:5 Floating constants are converted to internal format as if at translation-time.